# Convert past datetimes using JS with browser support

Tags: javascript, datetime, timezone

## toLocaleString() is deprecated but seems to lack replacement

---

I have a website where I store member post dates in this format: YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS

The problem is that these dates are all stored with the timezone UTC and I want to convert these dates using JS to the users OS timezone. I know I could just ask users to input their timezone but I would like to try something new which require as little user interaction as possible. The goal of the site is to make a forum which is incredibly easy and straightforward to use.

I have almost gotten it to work the way I want but it currently only supports Chrome it seems like. This is not good enough since I plan on having a lot of users.

Since the timezone offset varies it is not good enough to only retrieve the current time offset which a lot of topics here seem to suggest. I want to accurately display for e.g. registration dates.

This is my current solution (timezone test only supports chrome as far as I can tell) it is also implemented on the whole website which is in beta.
https://ingsan.net/timezone/

Source code below

```
var d = new Date();
var tzName = d.toLocaleString('en', {timeZoneName:'short'}).split('').pop();

var cusid_ele = document.getElementsByClassName('timestamp');
for (var i = 0; i < cusid_ele.length; ++i) {
  var timestamp = cusid_ele[i];  
  timestamp.innerHTML += " "+tzName;
  t = new Date(timestamp.innerHTML);
  usertime = t.toLocaleString()
  timestamp.innerHTML = usertime;
}
```

I have used this site for years without asking but this time I seem to be unable to find a topic similar enough to mine.

The method I use which might be questionably is simply replacing objects inside the assigned class name. I plan to do other classes for other format outputs.

```
<p>Register date: <span class="timestamp">2016-01-31 20:12:55</span></p>
```

If you got a solution to this issue I would very much appreciate it. I am no professional and never went to any course but I have managed to make ingsan.net on my own. Help a humble student out ;)

Comment: What you are trying to accomplish isn't very clear, but a javascript library like [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) might be helpful with time zone issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you're doing is converting from UTC to the browser's local time zone, you do not need to actually try to figure out what time zone that is.  Just be sure your input is clearly identified as UTC, and the default behavior of the `Date` object is to display values in the browser's local time zone.

```
var input = "2016-01-31 20:12:55";
var d = new Date(input + " UTC");
var s = d.toString();
```

The resulting string will vary by implementation and time zone, such as (a few examples):

```
"Sun Jan 31 2016 12:12:55 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)"
"Sun Jan 31 2016 15:12:55 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)"
"Mon Feb 01 2016 01:42:55 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)"
"Mon Feb 01 2016 09:12:55 GMT+1300 (New Zealand Daylight Time)"
```

This will work in all browsers.  The only problem is that you don't have control over the *format* of the output string.  That's where `toLocaleString` can help, though as you pointed out - it's not necessarily implemented in all browsers.  However, you seemed to think it was deprecated, and it is not.  It's actually part of a newer specification (ECMA-402), which just is not widely implemented everywhere (yet).

You have other options though.  You could build the output string yourself, like this:

```
var z = function(x) {return x < 10 ? '0' + x : x};
var s = d.getFullYear() + '-' + z(d.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + z(d.getDate()) + ' '
      + z(d.getHours()) + ':' + z(d.getMinutes()) + ':' + z(d.getSeconds());
```

Of course you could figure out how to adjust to 12 hour format, use different separators, different date-field ordering (YMD vs DMY vs MDY), etc.

Or, you could just use a library such as [moment.js](http://momentjs.com) which is already equipped for that.

```
var input = "2016-01-31 20:12:55";
var m = moment.utc(input).local(); // parse as UTC, then switch to local mode
var s = m.format(); // use any of the format parameters you wish
```